# Jupyterhub with dockerspawner does not run - error 502

Tags: docker, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to set up a multiuser jupyter setup. For this case I've set up an jupyterhub with RemoteCSVAuthenticator and DockerSpawner.

Authentication seems to work fine and also if I log in, a docker-container is started. But after logging in I only get an 502 Error-Message:

```
502 : Bad Gateway
The error was:
Failed to check authorization (upstream problem)
```

The jupyterhost logfile shows no errors. The dockercontainer is the plain 
`jupyterhub/singleuser`.

Can anyone tell me where to start?

---

After trying to digg deeper into the problem I found that if I try to access the jupyter-process inside the docker container (e.g. http://172.17.0.36:8888/) it always throws error 404 - page not found. I don't think this is normal. Maybe this is the cause for the configurable-http-proxy to throw the "Bad Gateway" error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. Since in our company we need to set a proxy I set `$http_proxy` and `$https_proxy` inside the Docker-Container. This made the jupyterhub-single running inside docker unable to open the connection to the host. My solution was to setup an local proxy on my host and forward local conenctions to the host everything else goes through the company's proxy.